# How to solve for orthogonal matrices from number of observations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose, we have observations of the product of 3 orthogonal matrices as 
$$
   \begin{align}
   K_{1}&=R_{l}M_{1}R_{r}\\
   K_{2}&=R_{l}M_{2}R_{r}\\
   \vdots& \vdots\\
   K_{n}&=R_{l}M_{n}R_{r}
   \end{align}
$$

where, $K{1},K_{2},\ldots,K_{n}$ are the observations of products, $R_{l}$ and $R_{r}$ are rotational matrices, $M{1},M_{2},\ldots,M_{n}$ are the matrices that represents reflections. If $K_{i}$ and $M_{i}$ are known for each observations. How can we solve for $R_{l}$ and $R_{r}$?

Note: Each matrices $R_{l},R_{r},$ and $M_{i}$ are 3 by 3 matrices.

Comment: Are $R_l$ and $R_r$ related somehow, or do they represent arbitrary rotations?

Comment: @Kajelad: They represent independent rotations.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the matrix entries of $R_l^{-1}$ and $R_r$ as variables, we have a system of linear equations given by the entries of $R_l^{-1} K_j = M_j R_r$.  Solve this system.  With any luck, the solution set will have small dimension (maybe just $1$).
Then you want to determine a solution such that $R_l^{-1}$ and $R_r$ are rotations (i.e. orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$).

EDIT:
Here's an example:
$$ \eqalign{ M_1 = \pmatrix{3/7 & -2/7 & -6/7\cr -2/7 & 6/7 & -3/7\cr
-6/7 & -3/7 & -2/7\cr}, \ & K_1 = \pmatrix{-124/245 & 132/245 & -33/49\cr
5676/15925 & -711/1225 & -2332/3185\cr 12507/15925 & 748/1225 & -324/3185\cr} \cr
M_2 = \pmatrix{-7/11 & 6/11 & -6/11\cr 6/11 & 9/11 & 2/11\cr -6/11 & 2/11 & 9/11\cr}, \ & K_2 = \pmatrix{108/385 &  281/385 & 48/77\cr 4468/25025 & 1152/1925 & -3909/5005\cr 23601/25025 &  -636/1925 & -188/5005\cr}\cr
M_3 = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 4/5 & 3/5\cr 0 & 3/5 & -4/5},\ & K_3 = \pmatrix{6/7 & 2/7 & -3/7\cr 4986/11375 & -9573/11375 & 718/2275\cr 3077/11375 & 5214/11375 & 1926/2275}}$$
Solving the equations for the entries of $R_l^{-1}$ and $R_r$, I get
$$ R_l^{-1} = \pmatrix{13 t/3 & 71 t/5 & -31 t/10 \cr 13t /2 & t & 41t /3 \cr
13 t & -157t/30 & -29 t/5},\ R_r = \pmatrix{91t/10  & -182t/15  & 0\cr 182t /15  & 91t /10  & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 91t /6 \cr}$$

for arbitrary $t$.  To get these to be orthogonal matrices, it's easy to check that you need $t = \pm 6/91$, and to have the determinant be $1$ you need $t= +6/91$.

Comment: How to find the solution of such that the rotation properties are maintained?